# Autoit image or text detection?

Tags: image, autoit

I have a png file - black background with list of images and text near these images. Is it possible to write Autoit script to either detect specific icon or title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can do what you want: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/65748-image-search-library/

The download on the first page is broken I think. The real download link is somewhere in the other pages in the thread.